# div aspect ratio by parent width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image which is 723 in width and 425 in height and I need the div.col-75-liquid element width to have that aspect ratio of the width and height of my images so when the browser is resized my slider will keep it aspect ratio I have to do this in jquery not in css. How do I do this in jquery? can someone make me an example of a div element that has that aspect ratio, the col-75-liquid is elastic so it will grow and shrink

When I have the aspect ratio I can then recreate my control on browser resize and set the new width and height for my control

```
<div class="col-75-liquid">
    <div class="img">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IS your `div` going to `hug` the image, or essentially be like a `border` around the image? And you just want it to be the same aspect ration of the image, correct? I can show you a solution, but you'll have to use a `window resize` handler.

Comment: Here is a page that gives a CSS only solution.http://wellcaffeinated.net/articles/2012/12/10/very-simple-css-only-proportional-resizing-of-elements/

Comment: use `%'s` instead of `pxs`

Comment: Yeah I have to use window resize because the outer parent size changes. The Image isn't going to be huge it won't fit whole window it's inside a center div which is liquid or flexible I just want my control to be responsive. And yeah I want it to keep it's aspect ratio of 723(width)/425(height)

Comment: Hard to tell from your question alone but I think you're looking at intrinsic ratios: http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/

Comment: It has to be done in jquery because it's a jquery control that calculates width and height and it doesn't use %

Comment: Answered for you. Let me know if that will fit the bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well, without your CSS and whatnot**, this will resize the parent div to 150% of the image's dimensions when the window is resized. This will maintain aspect, because you are comparing the parent to the image itself. Let me know if you'd like me to expand further.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img id="slide1" src="whatever.jpg" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('#wrapper').height($('#slide1').height() * 1.5);
    $('#wrapper').width($('#slide1').width() * 1.5);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/fJpwf/2/

I didn't do anything responsive, but it would act responsively if your other `CSS` (or even other jQuery functions) are controlling that. I can throw another example if you'd like.

## EDIT:

Didn't understand the question.

**Try something like this:**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/fJpwf/3/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="slide1" src="image.jpg" />
</div>

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.wrapper').height($('.wrapper').width() * .58);    
});
```

This will make the wrapper maintain the aspect ratio of your image despite what size it is.

**In other words, if you know the `width` of your parent element, do something like:**

```
$('.parent').height($('.parent').width() * .58);
```

**If you know the height and need the width, use:**

```
$('.parent').width($('.parent').height() * 1.7);
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all. It's suppose to keep an aspect ratio of the image based on the parents width so I you need to calculate the ratio and get the width and height and then recreate the control

Comment: You want your IMAGE to inherit the aspect ratio of the DIV? That doesn't make sense based on your question, because you said you have a `static sized` image... Because if your images are `723px x 425px`, this will make the container around them be the EXACT same aspect ratio (`1.7`).

Comment: I want the image to keep it's aspect ratio base on the parent width so the parent could be any size but the div holding the image gets bigger or smaller and keeping its aspect ratio

Comment: Oh, easy. One second.

Comment: forget the div holding the image imagine the div.child has that aspect ratio of the width and height and when you resize the parent it change the size of the child

Comment: The I can get the width and height and then recreate load again my control

Comment: Isn't the `child` your `img` which you want a static size? You gotta throw me a bone here dude, cause I think I'm confused.

Comment: Or another way to look at it is this how do you get the new width and height of div that has the aspect ratio 723w and 425h

Comment: how do you get .58 in you calculation for height of the div

Comment: In order to make this work, we need to have at least ONE size. An equation like `a + b + c = d` will never work if we don't have at least SOMETHING to go with. The above code I edited assumes your `wrapper` is 100% in width, and modifies the height to reflect the aspect ratio.

Comment: I think you are getting somewhere now. How do you remove a control and recreate it on resize that's another question too.

Comment: If you have another question, and considering I'm the only answer here, I would suggest posting another question on the forums if you have a different issue. That comment above doesn't really give me anything to go off. I believe I've answered the question asked (recently updated base of post for explanation). If you feel this has helped solve the problem, please accept the answer. More than happy to explain via **chat** if you had questions on THIS question.

Comment: ty sir. Good luck, and perhaps I'll see your other question (feel free to add it into comments here). I'd advise adding a little more context, cause that was a tricky question to decode what you were asking.